# iOS Keyboard remove iPhone iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6, keyboard, dismiss

Something is driving me nuts, may be somebody can help. I am currently testing something in a Universal app with a textField. I defined an action on my TextField (with didEndOnExit)

```
- (IBAction)textFieldTouched:(UITextField *)sender {
[self.textFieldEnter resignFirstResponder];
_textFieldContent.text = _textFieldEnter.text;
_textFieldContent.hidden=NO;
NSLog (@"Content of field : %@", _textFieldContent.text);
```

}

When I use it on my iPhone iOS7, I touch the textField, the keyboard appears, I type something, I hit return, the keyboard goes.

When I use it on my iPad iOS6, I touch the textField, the keyboard appears, I type something, I hit return, nothing happens. In order to have the keyboard go away, I need to hit the down-right little keyboard. 
It was working on other apps I wrote in iOS6, so why not now ? I have tried to auto-enable return key for the ipad (what is even not enabled for the iPhone) but it doesn't change anything.

Can't be a big thing but it's irritating.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: better to write code in TextField delegate method it works fine.   - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField { [self.textFieldEnter resignFirstResponder];
_textFieldContent.text = _textFieldEnter.text;
_textFieldContent.hidden=NO;
NSLog (@"Content of field : %@", _textFieldContent.text);}

Comment: Thank you Aruna. You need to return something, don't you?

Comment: it still doesn't work by clicking on Return on the keyboard